# Control Bluestacks with python

Tags: python, android, mouse, bluestacks

I would like to send keystrokes to Bluestacks (which I can already do by sending keys to the process) and tap on the screen of the emulated device. I have a problem with tapping since I would not like to use the mouse to do this. If I had to use the mouse I couldn't use my computer while running my bot.

If you have any other ideas on how to tap the emulator screen using Python please tell me.

Comment: How is this related to mouse and android, also, show us your code.

Comment: Well, I thought it was related to the mouse since my question included it, also I don't have code because I have no idea how to interact with bluestacks from python apart from moving and clicking the mouse. My problem is tapping on the screen without using the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do other things while your bot is interacting with Bluestacks you can use **win32gui** from **pywin32** module https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/. It can send keys to Bluestacks in background, that way you still can use your mouse while your bot is doing its job.